# How to use pivot and group by in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have to write query in hive and how to write the pivot in hive

Data:

```
Date| Column1| Column2| Amount

20130405| A| P=1

20130405| A| p=2

20130405| A| Q=3

20130405|A|Q=2

20130406| A| p=2

20130406|A|p=1

20130406|A|q=3

20130405| B| P=1

20130405|B|Q=1

20130406|B| Q=2
```

My output should be:

```
Column1|Column2|20130405|20130406|Difference(20130406-20130405)

A| P| 3| 1,-2

A| Q| 5| 3| -2

B| P|1|0|1

B|Q|1|2,-1
```

Can someone help me on this?

I have try this:

select a.column1,a.column2,(a.20130405-a.20130406)as "Difference"
(select column1,column2,sum(case when Date=20130405 then Amount else 0 END) as "20130405",sum(case when Date=20130406 then Amount else 0 END) as "20130406"
from table1
group by column1,column2
order by column1,column2)a

order by column1,column2

In this query i have hardcoded the date through case, sum someone help me how to use pivot in hive

Comment: :Mention what you have tried and where you are struck.

Comment: Also, could you reformat your input and output above? Try to have proper alignment and consistency in using uppercase/ lowercase, delimiters.